# Formally Proofing the ¬(¬ ∧ ) can become P ∧¬Q

Tags: formal-proofs

I am doing a proof and to finish it of I need this to work... I know it can be done but i'm not sure how to get from ¬(¬ ∧ ) to P ∧¬Q and what laws should be applied

Comment: Which kind of proof system do you want to carry this out in? There are several (equivalent but) very different ways to construct proof systems for propositional calculus.

Comment: By the way, the rewriting you want to do is not valid. To make it valid, one -- but not both -- of your $\land$s should be a $\lor$.

Comment: I don't want to use de-morgans law if thats what your stating

Comment: No matter what you want or don't want to use, the thing you've written down is not valid. For example, if $P$ and $Q$ are both true, then $\neg(\neg P\land Q)$ is true, but $P\land \neg Q$ is false.

Comment: ok thx alot...still helped relized I was going in the wrong direction was much simpler  still thanks for your help...